# How to solve this equations in modular arithmetic? $6247x \equiv 1139 \pmod{9461}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

> $6247x \equiv 1139 \pmod{9461}$, where $9461$ is a prime number

I just started learning modular equations and I have no idea how to solve this advanced questions.

Comment: Do you know Euclid's division algorithm to find the gcd of two numbers ?

Comment: yes. Use it to find the gcd of 6247 and 1139?

Comment: No, the gcd of $6247$ and $9461$, which is $1$ in this case because $9461$ is a prime. The extended algorithm (working the equations backwards) finds integers $a,b$ with $6247a+9461b=1$.

Comment: Then, you know that $a$ is a multiplicative inverse of $6247$ in the ring $\mathbb Z_{9461}$ (which is even a field because $9461$ is prime).

Comment: $6247*1934 + 9461* -1277 = 1$ So, $a$ is 1934 which is the multiplicative inverse of 6247.

Comment: http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/engg2440/hw/16H03.pdf <--- Remember to give credit to this question.

Comment: So, $1934$ is the multiplicative inverse. Multiply it with $1139$ and reduce modulo $9461$. The result is $7874$.

Comment: @Matthew Why the deletion?

Comment: A convenient method to compute modular inverses is [this version of the extended Euclidean algorithm.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Answer (score 1):

I will show the method step by step for a much easier example :

$$33x\equiv 41\mod 101$$

$$101=3\cdot 33+2$$

$$33=16\cdot 2+1$$

$$2=2\cdot 1+0$$

Therefore, $gcd(33,101)=1$ and the extended algorithm gives

$$1=33-16\cdot 2=33-16\cdot (101-3\cdot 33)=49\cdot 33-16\cdot 101$$

Therefore $33^{-1}=49$ in $\mathbb Z_{101}$

So, the solution is $$x=41\cdot 49=2009\equiv 90\mod 101$$

If you get a negative number $a$ , you can choose $p+a$ instead to get a positive solution. (Here $p=101$ , so if the result would have been $-40$, we could have used $-40+101=61$ instead).

The modulus $p$ need not be a prime number. The method works always , if the $gcd$ is $1$.